# React threefibre zooming from zoombar and scroll

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a 3d scene built with react threefibre and I'm able to zoom in and out with both mousewheel and a DOM eleemnt zoombar in this scene.
the demo of the scene can be seen here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zooming-using-multiple-inputs-lub391

right now, when you zoom with mousewheel, zoombar stays the same, but I want the it change dependant on the mousewheel.

- note that I don't want to use mouse wheel event because I may have more sources that also change the zoom and I want the zoombar to be dependant on them too. so the proper way is to add an event listener on camera movement. I wasn't able to do that because whatever I do makes an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an EventListener on the identified Canvas that listens for mousewheel events like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById('map-canvas')?.addEventListener('mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false)

    return () => {
      document.getElementById('map-canvas')?.removeEventListener('mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false)
    }
  }, [])

return (
  <Canvas id="map-canvas"></Canvas>
)
```

The `onMouseWheel` function adds the desired value to the previously created context.